# How are oncogenes targeted for therapy?

Tags: cancer, gene-expression

How would oncogenes be targeted for therapy and are there any examples of existing therapies for such cancers if the gene was upregulated (i) as a result of copy number variation and (ii) due to increased promoter activity?

Comment: You mean by targeting the mutated gene in the cells or by targeting the gene product of the mutation?